# Colocação pronominal na norma culta

Tags: colocação-pronominal

Gostaria de entender o porquê da utilização da sintaxe de colocação pronominal, e quais as normas e regras para as utilizar na forma culta.

- **Ênclise:** uso do pronome pessoal oblíquo DEPOIS do verbo, ligado por hífen.
- **Próclise:** uso do pronome pessoal oblíquo ANTES do verbo, sem hífen.
- **Mesóclise:** uso do pronome pessoal oblíquo no MEIO do verbo, interligado por hífens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

São várias regras, dependedo de tempos verbais e etc, acredito que aqui é uma boa referência.

> É o estudo da colocação dos pronomes oblíquos átonos (me, te, se, o,
>   a, lhe, nos, vos, os, as, lhes) em relação ao verbo.
>
> Os pronomes átonos podem ocupar 3 posições: antes do verbo (próclise),
>   no meio do verbo (mesóclise) e depois do verbo (ênclise).
>
> Esses pronomes se unem aos verbos porque são “fracos” na pronúncia.
>
> PRÓCLISE Usamos a próclise nos seguintes casos:
>
> (1) Com palavras ou expressões negativas: não, nunca, jamais, nada,
>   ninguém, nem, de modo algum.
>
> - Nada me perturba.
> - Ninguém se mexeu.
> - De modo algum me afastarei daqui.
> - Ela nem se importou com meus problemas.
>
> (2) Com conjunções subordinativas: quando, se, porque, que, conforme,
>   embora, logo, que.
>
> - Quando se trata de comida, ele é um “expert”.
> - É necessário que a deixe na escola.
> - Fazia a lista de convidados, conforme me lembrava dos amigos sinceros.
>
> (3) Advérbios
>
> - Aqui se tem paz.
> - Sempre me dediquei aos estudos.
> - Talvez o veja na escola.
>
> OBS: Se houver vírgula depois do advérbio, este (o advérbio) deixa de
>   atrair o pronome.
>
> - Aqui, trabalha-se.
>
> (4) Pronomes relativos, demonstrativos e indefinidos.
>
> - Alguém me ligou? (indefinido)
> - A pessoa que me ligou era minha amiga. (relativo)
> - Isso me traz muita felicidade. (demonstrativo)
>
> (5) Em frases interrogativas.
>
> - Quanto me cobrará pela tradução?
>
> (6) Em frases exclamativas ou optativas (que exprimem desejo).
>
> - Deus o abençoe!
> - Macacos me mordam!
> - Deus te abençoe, meu filho!
>
> (7) Com verbo no gerúndio antecedido de preposição EM.
>
> - Em se plantando tudo dá.
> - Em se tratando de beleza, ele é campeão.
>
> (8) Com formas verbais proparoxítonas
>
> - Nós o censurávamos.
>
> MESÓCLISE Usada quando o verbo estiver no futuro do presente (vai
>   acontecer – amarei, amarás, ...) ou no futuro do pretérito (ia
>   acontecer mas não aconteceu – amaria, amarias, ...)
>
> - Convidar-me-ão para a festa.
> - Convidar-me-iam para a festa.
>
> Se houver uma palavra atrativa, a próclise será obrigatória.
>
> - Não (palavra atrativa) me convidarão para a festa.
>
> ÊNCLISE Ênclise de verbo no futuro e particípio está sempre errada.
>
> - Tornarei-me....... (errada)
> - Tinha entregado-nos..........(errada)
>
> Ênclise de verbo no infinitivo está sempre certa.
>
> - Entregar-lhe (correta)
> - Não posso recebê-lo. (correta)
>
> Outros casos:
>   - Com o verbo no início da frase: Entregaram-me as camisas.
>   - Com o verbo no imperativo afirmativo: Alunos, comportem-se.
>   - Com o verbo no gerúndio: Saiu deixando-nos por instantes.
>   - Com o verbo no infinitivo impessoal: Convém contar-lhe tudo.
>
> OBS: se o gerúndio vier precedido de preposição ou de palavra
>   atrativa, ocorrerá a próclise:
>
> - Em se tratando de cinema, prefiro o suspense.
> - Saiu do escritório, não nos revelando os motivos.
>
> COLOCAÇÃO PRONOMINAL NAS LOCUÇÕES VERBAIS Locuções verbais são
>   formadas por um verbo auxiliar + infinitivo, gerúndio ou particípio.
>
> AUX + PARTICÍPIO: o pronome deve ficar depois do verbo auxiliar. Se
>   houver palavra atrativa, o pronome deverá ficar antes do verbo
>   auxiliar.
>
> - Havia-lhe contado a verdade.
> - Não (palavra atrativa) lhe havia contado a verdade.
>
> AUX + GERÚNDIO OU INFINITIVO: se não houver palavra atrativa, o
>   pronome oblíquo virá depois do verbo auxiliar ou do verbo principal.
>
> Infinitivo
>   - Quero-lhe dizer o que aconteceu.
>   - Quero dizer-lhe o que aconteceu.
>
> Gerúndio
>   - Ia-lhe dizendo o que aconteceu.
>   - Ia dizendo-lhe o que aconteceu.
>
> Se houver palavra atrativa, o pronome oblíquo virá antes do verbo
>   auxiliar ou depois do verbo principal.
>
> Infinitivo
>   - Não lhe quero dizer o que aconteceu.
>   - Não quero dizer-lhe o que aconteceu.
>
> Gerúndio
>   - Não lhe ia dizendo a verdade.
>   - Não ia dizendo-lhe a verdade.

Fonte: [InfoEscola](http://www.infoescola.com/portugues/colocacao-pronominal-proclise-mesoclise-enclise/)