# A ordem, entre o pronome oblíquo e o verbo, está errada?

Tags: verbos, pronomes

**1)** Algum dos três **"me"** da frase abaixo tem que vir após o verbo?

> — Aeromoça! Tem um cara que eu não conheço **me** acusando, **me** ameaçando e **me** insultando!

**2)** O **"lhe"**, da frase abaixo, também tem que vir após o verbo?

> — Senhor, **lhe** peço gentilmente para que deixe a moça em paz ou terei que expulsá-lo do voo!

**3)** Algum dos dois últimos **"se"**, da frase abaixo, ainda tem que vir após o verbo?

> ♪ Pode-se, **se** deve e **se** vai aprender muito! ♫ ()

No inglês e no espanhol não tem erro. No inglês, o verbo sempre vem antes do pronome; já no espanhol, a ordem tanto faz e apenas se deve aglutinar o verbo ao pronome como uma única palavra se o verbo vier antes no caso.

Comment: Na variedade europeia, nos casos em que tens dúvidas é sempre depois do verbo (no último possivelmente com subida, ou seja "vai-se aprender" ou "vai aprender-se") . Mas acjo que queres o uso no Brasil, certo?

Answer (score 1):

**Dúvida #1**

No exemplo dado, você pode utilizar a regra da ênclise (pronome após o verbo) ou próclise (pronome antes do verbo).

**Dúvida #2**

No exemplo 2, a função do *lhe*, morfologicamente falando, é de pronome oblíquo. Portanto, deve seguir a lógica da ênclise, visto que é início de oração. Ou seja, ficar após o verbo.

> — Senhor, peço-**lhe** gentilmente para que deixe a moça em paz ou terei que expulsá-lo do voo!

**Dúvida #3**

No exemplo 3, a função do *se* é *Índice de Indeterminação do Sujeito*. Este índice, também conhecido como partícula, sempre acompanha verbos na 3ª pessoa do singular que não possua sujeito. A partícula de indeterminação implica, basicamente, um sujeito genérico e/ou impreciso. A posição da partícula segue a regra da próclise e ênclise.

No início de orações ou quando não houver palavras atrativas, usa-se a partícula após o verbo (em regra):

```
 Pode-se, deve-se  e  vai-se aprender muito!
└─┬─┘└┬─┘ └─┬─┘└┬┘└┬┘└─┬─┘└┬┘└───┬───┘└──┬──┘
  │   │     │   │  │   │   │     │       └── Advérbio
  │   │     │   │  │   │   │     └────────── Verbo
  │   │     │   │  │   │   └──────────────── Pronome (Pode usar a regra da ênclise ou próclise)
  │   │     │   │  │   └──────────────────── Verbo
  │   │     │   │  └──────────────────────── Conjunção (permite o uso do pronome antes do verbo "vai"
  │   │     │   └─────────────────────────── Pronome (Ênclise obrigatória)
  │   │     └─────────────────────────────── Verbo
  │   └───────────────────────────────────── Pronome (Ênclise obrigatória)
  └───────────────────────────────────────── Verbo
```

> Pode-*se*, deve-*se* e vai-*se* aprender muito! [**Ênclise**]
>   Pode-*se*, deve-*se* e se vai aprender muito! [**Ênclise / Próclise**]

No último exemplo, como há a conjunção aditiva *e*, pode usá-la antes ou depois do verbo.

Quando houver palavras atrativas, a partícula deverá ficar antes do verbo

```
  Aqui  se   faz;  aqui   se   paga!
└──┬──┘└─┬─┘└─┬─┘ └──┬──┘└─┬─┘└─┬─┘
   │     │    │      │     │    └── Verbo
   │     │    │      │     └─────── Pronome (próclise)
   │     │    │      └───────────── Advérbio (palavra atrativa
   │     │    └──────────────────── Verbo
   │     └───────────────────────── Pronome (próclise)
   └─────────────────────────────── Advérbio (palavra atrativa)
```

---

As [palavras atrativas](http://educacao.globo.com/portugues/assunto/usos-da-lingua/colocacao-pronominal.html) são:

- **Palavras de sentido negativo:** Você nem se preocupou com meus problemas!
- **Advérbios:** Aqui se pode viver tranquilamente.
- **Pronomes Indefinidos:** Alguém me telefonou?
- **Pronomes Interrogativos:** Que me falta conhecer?
- **Pronomes Relativos:** A pessoa que te telefonou não se identificou.
- **Pronomes Demonstrativos Neutros:** Isso o comoveu demais.
- **Conjunções Subordinativas:** Chamava pelos nomes, conforme se lembrava deles.

Comment: Complemento: https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/4383/2759